# How to make log4j record to a file and print to console

Tags: java, log4j

I can make the log to go the console but I cant seem to make it go to a log file. Here is my `properties` file.

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, LOG , stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%5p %d{d/MM/yy HH:mm:ss}:%m%n
# log4j.appender.LOG.Threshold=INFO

log4j.appender.LOG=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.LOG.File=C:\dev\harry\data\logs\core.log
log4j.appender.LOG.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.LOG.Append=true
log4j.appender.LOG.layout.ConversionPattern=%5p %d{d/MM/yy HH:mm:ss}:%m%n
# log4j.appender.LOG.Threshold=INFO
```

Comment: doesn't the \ have to be \\   ? That's true in most properties files

Comment: @MJB: Thank you. Your suggestion solved my problem. Can you format your comment into a separate answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that your single \ should be \\. This is true in most properties files.

Answer (score 1):

There are some issues with the \ in the file path that need to be fixed.  The syntax is a bit cryptic but the way to log to multiple locations is to attach a named logging appender to the root logger.  In this example this is:

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, LOG , stdout
```

`DEBUG` is a logging level (threshold filter) to use for the root logger.

`LOG` is the name of a logging appender

`stdout` is the name of a second appender

The logging appenders are specified by

```
log4j.appender.{logging-appender-name}={some.log4j.appender.class}
log4j.appender.{logging-appender-name}.{some-other-property}=...
```

Where `{logging-appender-name}` is a name selected by yourself (in this case LOG and stdout) and `{some.log4j.appender.class}` is one of the many log4j [logging appender classes](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/Appender.html) such as [DailyRollingFileAppender](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/DailyRollingFileAppender.html) or [ConsoleAppender](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/ConsoleAppender.html).

Answer (score 0):

I would have added:
log4j.appender.LOG.Threshold=ALL

I'm not sure what the default is.